# Java: IndexOutOfBounds exception and eventDispatch

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, jcomponent

I apologize if the title is not descriptive of the issue I'm having.
I'm developing a testing GUI for a simple GUI calculator. the test GUI would allow the user to click on components of calculator GUI in order to record them. And then start putting values in those components to test the calculator's functionality.

Essentially, I set up three classes MyListener, ThreadRunner and TestGUI. The TestGUI has two buttons, one so that the user can click on the calculator JTextfields and record them using methods in ThreadRunner which has an ArrayList to store JTextFields and other variables to store other components. The other button is to set values into the JTextFields stored in the ArrayList through a method in TestRunner. The problem I'm having is that when I click the second button to set new values I get the exception IndexOutOfBounds along with other ones. I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out for the past couple of days, so any help would be much much appreciated. Thank you!

```
public class ThreadRunner extends Thread {
//ChooseInput ci = new ChooseInput();
//List<String> inputVal = ci.getInput();

List<JTextField> listOfTextFields = new ArrayList<>();
JTextField output;
JButton goButton;

public void getInputField(JTextField a) {
    listOfTextFields.add(a);
    System.out.println("getinput func. in thread runner works");
    //System.out.println(a);
    System.out.print(listOfTextFields.get(0));
}

public void getOutputField(JTextField a) {
    output = a;
}

public void getButton(JButton a) {
    goButton = a;
}

public void go() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // to test if go() can access listOfTextFields
        System.out.print(listOfTextFields.get(i));
    }
    listOfTextFields.get(0).setText("10");
    listOfTextFields.get(1).setText("20");
    System.out.println("func go() works");
}
}


public class MyListener implements AWTEventListener {
ThreadRunner t = new ThreadRunner();
public MyListener(ThreadRunner t) {
    t = t;
}

@Override
public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {

    if (event.paramString().substring(0, 13).equals("MOUSE_CLICKED")) {
        System.out.println("Click happens");
        Object o = event.getSource();
        if (o.getClass().equals(JTextField.class)) {
            JTextField tf = (JTextField) o;
            if (tf.isEditable()) {
                t.getInputField(tf);
                System.out.println("TR shpuld have a field");
            } else {
                t.getOutputField(tf);
            }
        }

        if (o.getClass().equals(JButton.class)) {
            JButton jb = (JButton) o;
            t.getButton(jb);
        }
    }
}
}

public class TestGUI {

public TestGUI() {
    final ThreadRunner tr = new ThreadRunner();
    final MyListener ml = new MyListener(tr);
    JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
    JButton b1 = new JButton("get locations");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("test");
    f1.setVisible(true);
    f1.setSize(500, 200);

    f1.getContentPane().add(b1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f1.getContentPane().add(b2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    b1.setVisible(true);
    b2.setVisible(true);

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            MyGUI gui = new MyGUI();
            gui.setSize(500, 300);
            gui.setVisible(true);
            gui.setLocation(200, 200);

            Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

            tk.addAWTEventListener(ml, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
        }
    }
    );

    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            tr.go();
        }
    }
    );
}
}
```

The error is produced when the go() method in ThreadRunner is invoked 
StackTrace:

```
run:
```

Click happens
Click happens
getinput func. in thread runner works
javax.swing.JTextField[,103,12,249x41,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@b97bc3,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]TR shpuld have a field
Click happens
getinput func. in thread runner works
javax.swing.JTextField[,103,12,249x41,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@b97bc3,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]TR shpuld have a field
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
Click happens
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at ThreadRunner.go(ThreadRunner.java:43)
    at TestGUI$2.actionPerformed(TestGUI.java:55)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Could you please paste the stacktrace? In addition to that, a minimal running example to reproduce the error would be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I just edited the post. Please let me know if I should add or change anything else.

Comment: Try public MyListener(ThreadRunner t) {
    this.t = t;
}

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Can you please give a brief explanation of why it works when I use "this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you used

```
ThreadRunner t = new ThreadRunner();
public MyListener(ThreadRunner t) {
    t = t;
}
```

which basically assigns the argument to itself instead of the local variable you defined above. By using `this` you explicitly specify that you d'like to reference the instance variable t instead of the argument.
So either use

```
ThreadRunner t = new ThreadRunner();
public MyListener(ThreadRunner t) {
    this.t = t;
}
```

Or rename your class variable to another name, e.g.

```
ThreadRunner ct = new ThreadRunner();
public MyListener(ThreadRunner t) {
    ct = t;
}
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you.
I have to implement a couple of other features to the program. In case I run into other problems, should I ask questions in this post or create another one?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess it would be better to open new posts so they get better visibility. In case you consider this problem to be solved, you may accept my answer so that others know that the problem has been solved for you.

Comment: I just accepted it. Unfortunately I wasn't able to vote up the answer because I'm a new member and this is actually my first post.

Comment: A feature that I need to implement is to let the user control the speed at which the TestGUI is inputting values into the textfields through a JSlider. how can i control ThreadRunner using a JSlider?